# How much char data can my string hold or use?

Tags: java, string, input, crash, ram

My program is to take a string of characters limited to the regular expression [gcatGCAT], and convert that string to a string of complementary characters. The complementary characters are g to c, c to g, a to u, t to a.

For example, the user inputted string, "gact", should produce "cuga".

However, when entering  a string of about length 50 characters or over(i didn't count how many i entered, just pressed the g and c key on my keyboard for a while.)  I think i used up alot of my computer's RAM, for the program froze, and my Operating system background changed or something. (I did not want to try and reproduce it, for i was scared)

Am i using too much ram in imputing such a large string and performing operations on it? Is there any way i can simplify this to not use as much memory, if that is the issue? I would realistically like to be able to accept something of 200 to 500 characters, with 1000 being the most optimal. I am a novice at coding so forgive me if i was wrong in anyway.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;

//getting my feet wet, 1/13/2015, program is to take a strand of nucleotides, G C  A  T, for DNA and give
//the complementary RNA strand, C G  U A.

public class practiceSixty {

public static void main(String[] args){
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

        String input = null;

        boolean loopControl = true;

        char nucleotide;

        int repeat;

    do{
          do{
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Enter the sequence of nucleotides(G,C,A and T) for DNA, no spaces ");

            }while(!input.matches("[GCATgcat]+")); //uses regular expresions, This method returns true if, and only if, this string matches the given regular expression.


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the data you entered is " + input);

            StringBuilder dna = new StringBuilder(input);

            for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {
            nucleotide = input.charAt(i);

                if(nucleotide == 'G' || nucleotide == 'g' )
                {
                    dna.setCharAt(i, 'c');
                }
                else if( nucleotide == 'C' || nucleotide == 'c')
                {
                    dna.setCharAt(i, 'g');
                }
                if(nucleotide == 'A' || nucleotide == 'a')
                {
                    dna.setCharAt(i, 'u');
                }
                else if(nucleotide == 'T' || nucleotide == 't')
                {
                    dna.setCharAt(i, 'a');
                }
            }
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the DNA is  , " + input + "  the RNA is  " + dna);

             repeat = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Press Yes to continue, No to quit ", "please confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

             }while(repeat == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
 }
});
}
}
```

Comment: Please, properly indent your code.

Comment: I don't see how your code would take for ever with 50 characters or even more.... may be the code readability could be improved a bit but to me it looks efficient enough. is your program actually consuming CPU time?

Comment: @ValentinRuano I am not sure how to determine that. All i know is that with 50 or more characters it froze a bit, and the GUI for the program went black. Thank you though.

Comment: @RoSiv depends on the computer... in Unix like systems (including Linux or MacOS) you can use 'top' from the command line... in windows the Task Manager; please google it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use string.replace().  However you can't just replace one with the other, because that will screw up later replacements.

```
input = input.toLowerCase();
input = input.replace('a','1');
input = input.replace('c','2');
input = input.replace('g','3');
input = input.replace('t','4');
input = input.replace('1','u');
input = input.replace('2','g');
input = input.replace('3','c');
input = input.replace('4','a');
```

Comment: I think that it is a bit of an overkill to create a new string for each replacement, you can do better.

Comment: EDIT: sorry I thought that it was a String rather than StringBuffer. Even so it seems that the original question code is more efficient anyway.